# How to remove special characters from NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am doing push notification application and i am getting device token <8c09362c 82d6b735 c82fb2d9 8070db6f f73419b3 9da15e34 72aba570 6fbf5a45>, I got that device token from NSData, have succesfully converted into NSString, however i only need to remove first and last special character < > from NSString

Comment: It looks like you are using the NSData description method, don't, it is meant for human readability, not program usage.

Comment: True.  `description` is not guaranteed to produce the same output in the next version of iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of way to achieve this:

One you can  use the way `bigkm` shows. Second  `Empty Stack` had suggest a better way too.

Here is one other way:

```
NSString *dataToken = @"<8c09362c 82d6b735 c82fb2d9 8070db6f f73419b3 9da15e34 72aba570 6fbf5a45>";
NSString *str = [dataToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to trim certain characters from a string, you can use *NSCharacterSet* and *stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:* method of *NSString*.

```
NSCharacterSet *chs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"];
string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:chs];
```

Answer (score 1):

simple

```
NSString *dataToken = @"<8c09362c 82d6b735 c82fb2d9 8070db6f f73419b3 9da15e34 72aba570 6fbf5a45>";
NSString *token = [dataToken substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, [dataToken length]-2)];
```